# bouncycastle + JBoss AS7: JCE cannot authenticate the provider BC

Tags: java, security, jboss, bouncycastle, jce

I use BouncyCastle for encryption in my application. When I run it standalone, everything works fine. However, if I put it in the webapp and deploy on JBoss server, I get a following error:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: error constructing MAC: java.security.NoSuchProviderException: JCE cannot authenticate the provider BC
(...)
root cause
java.lang.Exception: error constructing MAC: java.security.NoSuchProviderException: JCE cannot authenticate the provider BC
(...)
root cause
java.io.IOException: error constructing MAC: java.security.NoSuchProviderException: JCE cannot authenticate the provider BC
    org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.JDKPKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad(Unknown Source)
    java.security.KeyStore.load(Unknown Source)
```

Here is a part of the code that causes this error:

```
    if (Security.getProvider(BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME) == null)
    {
        Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
    }

    // Read the Private Key
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12", BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME);
    ks.load(new FileInputStream(certificatePath), privateKeyPassword.toCharArray());
```

And maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>bouncycastle</groupId>
    <artifactId>bcmail-jdk16</artifactId>
    <version>140</version>
</dependency>
```

Do you know how could I deploy it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Do not deploy the bouncy-castle jar as a part of your your webapp (WEB-INF/lib). You need this file in compiliation time of course, but on JBOSS it should be here:

```
$JBOSS_HOME/server/default/lib/
```

instead of

```
yourapp/WEB-INF/lib
```

Comment: Why is that the case?

Comment: I am using jboss-eap-6.4 in JDK 1.8 and I have not server directory

Comment: This was all I needed, I'm actually glad this is the accepted answer. +1

Answer (score 47):

For JBoss AS7 bouncy castle needs to be deployed as a server module. This replaces the `server/default/lib` mechanism of earlier versions (as mentioned in Gergely Bacso's answer).

JBoss AS7 uses jdk1.6+. When using JBoss AS7 with jdk1.6 we need to make sure we are using bcprov-jdk16.

Create a Jboss module (a folder $JBOSS_HOME/modules/org/bouncycastle/main).
Put the bouncy castle jars that you want to be globally available in it, along with a `module.xml` file that looks like this:

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="org.bouncycastle">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="bcprov-jdk16-1.46.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api" slot="main" export="true"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

Once you have setup the module you need to make it available to your deployments. There are two ways:

### 1. Globally via standalone.xml

In $JBOSS_HOME/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml replace

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:1.0"/>
```

with

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:1.0">
    <global-modules>
        <module name="org.bouncycastle" slot="main"/>
    </global-modules>
</subsystem>
```

The jar libraries will now be available across all applications (and this will "emulate" adding to the classpath as was possible in jboss 4,5,6 etc)

### 2. For a specific deployment (preferred)

Add a module dependency entry to the ear's `META-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml` file, under the  section, eg:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.1">
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.bouncycastle" slot="main" export="true" />
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Comment: What is the reason behind this? Why does it work if it is run standalone and needs to be a module when run in JBoss? Are modules not verified but a jar inside of WEB-INF/lib is?

Comment: seriously, you saved me :) i was getting the same error with RSA JSAFE provider but able to get rid of it now with this workaround. Thanks a lot

Comment: In wildfly-9.0.2.Final the module folder for BouncyCastle already exists at `<HOME>/modules/system/layers/base/org/bouncycastle/main/` so you only need to make it available to your deployments (globally or for a single app).  Also note that in standalone.xml the subsystem `"urn:jboss:domain:ee"` already exists so you have only to add the tag `<global-modules>` to its content.

Comment: @Pino can you please provide more detail with example for beginner.

Comment: @Awanish My comment is a little update to the main answer.  Refer to the answer for a description of the changes you have to make to Wildfly's xml.

Answer (score 13):

But if You change server from JBoss to other (for example Glassfish) You have the same problem.
The better solition for me are changes in jdk.
You shoud add Bouncy Castle to security providers on Your java platform in two steps:
**1.** Copy BC librarys (currently bcpkix-jdk15on-149.jar, bcprov-jdk15on-149.jar) to directory **$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/ext/**
**2.** Register BC provider: edit file **$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/java.security** and under line

```
security.provider.1=sun.security.provider.Sun
```

add Your BC provider

```
security.provider.2=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
```

Change numbers of rest providers. The whole block of providers should be similar to:

```
security.provider.1=sun.security.provider.Sun
security.provider.2=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
security.provider.3=sun.security.rsa.SunRsaSign
security.provider.4=sun.security.ec.SunEC
security.provider.5=com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider
security.provider.6=com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE
security.provider.7=sun.security.jgss.SunProvider
security.provider.8=com.sun.security.sasl.Provider
security.provider.9=org.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.XMLDSigRI
security.provider.10=sun.security.smartcardio.SunPCSC
```

And now You must just restart the java server.

Comment: Sorry, You don't need change providers. Just add under SunPCSC provider next number of providers such as: `security.provider.10=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider`
BC provider does not have to be the second. Might be the last.

Comment: @KrzysztofSzewczyk But doesnt bounty castle provider need the highest provider here i.e 1. Since here priority will be given from 1 to 10.

Answer (score 0):

As I put in some other thread it can be also added programmatically by putting the line:

Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());

Source:
[jce cannot authenticate the provider bc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32775478/jce-cannot-authenticate-the-provider-bc)

Answer (score 0):

For those who don't want to change server level config,

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>  
   <deployment>  
      <resources>  
         <resource-root path="WEB-INF/lib/bcprov-jdk16-1.46.jar" use-physical-code-source="true"/>  
      </resources>  
   </deployment>  
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

adding the bouncy castle jars with use-physical-code-source worked for me