# SecurityException with Bouncy Castle

Tags: java, macos, encryption, bouncycastle, jasypt

I am on Mac OS and getting this issue after performing software update on my mac.

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: JCE cannot authenticate the provider BC
    at javax.crypto.SunJCE_b.a(DashoA13*..)
    at javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(DashoA13*..)
    at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEByteEncryptor.initialize(StandardPBEByteEncryptor.java:667)
    ... 95 more
Caused by: java.util.jar.JarException: Cannot parse jar:file:/Users/himajumdar/Work/jboss/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/tmp/a00c-b5p2h4-hgi84jo1-1-hgi84qe5-w/csa.ear!/lib/bcprov-jdk15-140.jar
    at javax.crypto.SunJCE_c.a(DashoA13*..)
    at javax.crypto.SunJCE_b.b(DashoA13*..)
    at javax.crypto.SunJCE_b.a(DashoA13*..)
    ... 98 more
```

I tried [these](http://www.randombugs.com/java/javalangsecurityexception-jce-authenticate-provider-bc.html) suggestions

1. Added security.provider.11=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
   to java.security
2. Added bcprov-jdk15-140.jar under /Home/jre/lib/ext

but that dint help. I tried updating jdk6 to jdk7 and did the same, and got a slight different error of **unsigned jar**

```
    at org.jboss.seam.Component.newInstance(Component.java:2132)
    ... 75 more
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: JCE cannot authenticate the provider BC
    at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.getInstance(JceSecurity.java:114)
    at javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(SecretKeyFactory.java:243)
    at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEByteEncryptor.initialize(StandardPBEByteEncryptor.java:667)
    ... 95 more
Caused by: java.util.jar.JarException: jar:file:/Users/himajumdar/Work/jboss/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/tmp/a00c-4nf5e1-hgiayarg-1-hgiayihg-w/csa.ear!/lib/bcprov-jdk15-140.jar has unsigned entries - csa-ejb-3.45.0.8-SNAPSHOT.jar
    at javax.crypto.JarVerifier.verifySingleJar(JarVerifier.java:462)
    at javax.crypto.JarVerifier.verifyJars(JarVerifier.java:322)
    at javax.crypto.JarVerifier.verify(JarVerifier.java:250)
```

I have tried this with jdk16-140.jar, but same result. Can someone think of any other option to overcome this issue? Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. I got rid of bouncy castle (bcprov-jdk15-140.jar) from my local jre/jdk ext directory
2. Copied bcprov-jdk15-140.jar under /jboss/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/lib/
3. Changed the dependency scope from default compile to provided
       
           bouncycastle
           bcprov-jdk15
           140
           provided
4. Added "security.provider.11=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider" to java.security

[This is my Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9534512/bouncycastle-jboss-as7-jce-cannot-authenticate-the-provider-bc)

Comment: Dear @Himalay , what configuration is required in the jboss when you set provided scope?

Comment: Also, I am using jboss-eap-6.4 and it has not default directory!

Answer (score 1):

Try the latest release. The provider jar of the current latest (1.48) can be found [here](http://www.bouncycastle.org/download/bcprov-ext-jdk15on-148.jar). The version (1.40) you are trying is pretty old by now.

Comment: Tried, that did not help me either.

Comment: Please make sure that there is absolutely no other BC provider in your class path. Check the `ext` folder of both your JDK(s) and JRE(s). If it finds one that it cannot authenticate you won't be able to add anything. Note that the latest provider has a different `.jar` file name...

Comment: thank you owlstead for your comments, your comments took me to right direction. I added my solution.

Comment: Glad to be of help, hmajumdar...